# Add href link to Image that has been displayed via js mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three images that each change to a second image on mouseover. On mouseover they also reset the others to the standard image. This all works fine.

However..

I would like each of the second images to be clickable links to another page.

Hope someone can help, many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#s1').mouseover(function(){
         $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/click-1.png');
          $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-2.jpg');
           $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-3.jpg');
     });
     $('#s2').mouseover(function(){
         $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-1.jpg');
          $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/click-2.png');
           $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-3.jpg');
     });
     $('#s3').mouseover(function(){
          $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-1.jpg');
           $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-2.jpg');
            $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/click-3.png');
     });


});
```

So the links would need to be on click-1.png, click-2.png, click-3.png.

```
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid" align="center">
    <div class="row row-centered ">
    <div id="top-box-1" class="col-sm-4">

   <img src="images/object/standard-1.jpg" id="s1" width="300" height="300" />
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-2" class="col-sm-4">

   <img src="images/object/standard-2.jpg"  id="s2" width="300" height="300" />
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-3" class="col-sm-4">

    <img src="images/object/standard-3.jpg"  id="s3" width="300" height="300" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post the html code as well. can't you just change the .attr for href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make each image tag (s1, s2, and s3) a link.  The actual src attribute of the img tag can change to display whatever image you want, it's really irrelevant.  After all, A user can only click on something they've moused over.

Comment: Yeah I missed the obvious, assumed the second image was something other than what was in the HTML. Many Thanks. All good now.